# java program over consumption of memory

Tags: java, string, performance

I have the following program which creates a hash map.

```
public class sample {
    private HashMap<String, String> joindata = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void map() 
    throws IOException{

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/tmp/table2"));

        String line;
        String[] tokens;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            tokens = line.split(",");

            if(tokens.length == 2)
               joindata.put(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
        }

    }
}
```

There seems to be some bug in this implementation as my heap is reaching 300M for this program when I take a 32M of file(/tmp/table2) to read from.

Can anyone suggest the optimizations that I can make to reduce the heap size, 300M of heap is clearly wrong implementation.

Comment: Have you done a heap dump?

Comment: yeah all the memory is taken by String and Char[]. There is clearly something going which I can not understand..

Comment: String and char[] which are owned by...?  Have you tried running this on a smaller file  and seeing if you still get an unexpected amount of memory?

Comment: yes, even with smaller files the heap explodes.. I just did a jmap to see the heap memory.. and it shows java.lang.string and Char[] taking max. memory...

Comment: And what were the strings?  Were they strings from your file as expected?  Were they hash keys?  Were they duplicates?

Comment: I am pretty new to java and havent explored the debugging tools completely.. I would guess there has to be a lot of duplicates there else 300M is difficult to fill in.

Comment: What is your `Xmx` - the GC won't really bother too much until your heap begins filling up.

Answer (score 1):

Java won't garbage collect until your heap fills up.  This memory consumption is not a problem.

Try locking up your main thread (e.g. call `(new Object()).wait()`, JMX in, do a garbage collect *then* a heap dump and your consumption will look much nicer.

Comment: I took a different approach.. I just did an empty loop from my main function after creating the hashmap, and things didnt change much..

Comment: an empty loop will have te inverse effect: it will consume 100% CPU, not letting the GC to run. The GC will choose to run when the CPU is idle, not when it's at 100%.

Comment: @djechlin including (new Object()).wait() gives me an illegalmonitorstateexception at runtime.

Comment: @djechlin I did, but that doesnt help in gc'ing

Comment: @djechlin The interesting behavior that I find in this program is that if I specify a heap size of 128m it still works, and on heap size of 256m there is no garbage collection that takes place which puts my heap usage to 200+M